# Ordering of items from database using SQL when the item is a Text

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am writing an Iphone app and using sqlite as my database. I have 10 objects and I need to order them by their category id. All the id are numbers (starting from 1 to 10).

The sql statement looks like this: `SELECT * FROM PACKAGE ORDER BY CATEGORYID ASC`

When I query, the result shows 1,10,2,3,4....9.

How do i solve this?

Comment: is `item10` the format of your `categoryID`?

Comment: no... this is the order... apologies...

Comment: Whats the datatype of the category id? I've seen the same effect when ordering numbers in string format

Comment: int... @KuyaJohn solution works ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe it's because that the categoryID is `TEXT`

```
SELECT * FROM PACKAGE ORDER BY CAST(CategoryID as INTEGER) ASC;
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/9daac/3)

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be with the data type of category id if its character then you will get the order as shown above.
but if the data type is numeric you will the it in correct format